# How to easily update entire rows in SQLite objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite, row

I have a database with about 150 columns, and would like to somehow update an entire row at once. I don't want to have to make one extremely long statement, and the columns are not all the same type. Is there a simple way to do this? Maybe with an NSMutableArray or something like BEGIN_COLUMN_MAP and COLUMN_ENTRY_AUTO in windows?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to modify data in SQLite is with an `UPDATE` statement.

If you don't want to write it yourself, you'll have to write a helper function that writes it for you.